# how do i add a youtube video player to my app using phonegap

Tags: youtube, phonegap-plugins, android-video-player

I'm having trouble finding how to add a YouTube video to my app.

I tried using a video player plugin, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: just use iframe to pass the youtube vide url eg: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0vrdgDdPApQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`